# How Accurate and Reliable Is the Block Timestamp in Smart Contract of Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: solidity

I was trying to buy an NFT while its auction time was over. It is an issue of Block. timestamp in the Markeplace's smart contract or not?

Comment: Um, no. I think it's an issue with you trying to buy the NFT after the end of it's auction period

Answer (score 0):

The block.timestamp is decided by the miner of the block, and they have a margin of some seconds. It could have happened that accordingly to the 'real-life' timestamp you were allowed to mint, but the miner set the timestamp a bit later than the auction deadline, and therefore your transaction reverted.